# Hibernate - handling SQLException

Tags: java, hibernate

All,

I am working on a project to upgrade hibernate from 4.1.4.FINAL to 5.2.17.FINAL. We have a bunch of Sybase stored procedures executed using org.hibernate.jdbc.Work. These stored procedures raise errors with some valid error codes like 20010. The error messages raised are caught and used to display on the UI. Here is the Sybase syntax to raise errors.

```
raiserror 20005 'Invalid'
```

I see that the new version of hibernate delegates SQL exceptions to convert to a specific exception in the JDBCException hierarchy. See -

```
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter
```

If it doesn't find a specific exception then it creates GenericJDBCException with a default message set. For example see

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.coordinateWork - 
Here the SQL exception is caught and the convert method is called with message 'error executing work'. So genericJDBCException.getMessage() will give this message.
```

I know that GenericJDBCException.getSQLException().getMessage() will give the actual sql exception message. But it is not feasible to change the existing code.

Is there a way to add our own delegate so that I can check the error code and return an exception with the message in SQLException. Or is there any better way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: I see that the dialect can be extended to add a delegate. Is there any other way?